# MongoDB finds docs but same update query updates 0 records

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to update certain documents by removing all the array elements inside `user`:

- `db.getCollection('units').find({"acctId": ObjectId('123')}).count()` **returns 3557 records**
- `db.getCollection('units').find({"accountId": ObjectId('123'), users: { $exists: true, $ne: [] } }).count()` **returns 710**

But!

- `db.getCollection('units').update({"accountId": ObjectId('123')}, { $set: { users: [] } }, { multi: true });` **updates 0 records**

The `find` query and `update` query have the exact same find criteria, and there are definitely non-empty user arrays to update. And the query runs successfully but no values are updated.

I must be missing something obvious?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I'll leave it here for anyone who has the same issue.

I was connected to a **secondary mongo instance** on a replica set. That only allows me to do reads. If you're having trouble updating or removing records, but the find queries work alright, then you're probably having read-only permission issues and need to reconnect to the **primary mongo instance on your replica set**.